# Running a Flask blueprint from the program

Tags: python, flask

I'm having problems with running my Flask application with a blueprint from the Python program. Here's what my code is and what I've tried.

```py
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask_login import login_required, current_user

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@main.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html', name=current_user.name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main.run(debug=True)
```

But my code throws the error `AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'run'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a blueprint directly, it should be imported into your main app and registered. Then, the main app will run, check the [official flask documentation here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/blueprints/).

Here is what you should do:

```
from flask import Flask
from yourapplication.mainblueprint import main

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(main)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Also, you can remove the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block from your blueprint, it won't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The Blueprint doesn't have the run attribute indeed. Instead you're missing the `Flask` object initialization, the `register_blueprint` method call and calling `Flask.run`.

Basic Blueprint usage (from the [documentation](https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html#how-do-you-use-them)):

```
# facebook/views/profile.py

from flask import Flask    
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

profile = Blueprint('profile', __name__)

@profile.route('/<user_url_slug>')
def timeline(user_url_slug):
    # Do some stuff
    return render_template('profile/timeline.html')

@profile.route('/<user_url_slug>/photos')
def photos(user_url_slug):
    # Do some stuff
    return render_template('profile/photos.html')

@profile.route('/<user_url_slug>/about')
def about(user_url_slug):
    # Do some stuff
    return render_template('profile/about.html')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(profile)
```